# JSON.parse throws - suddenly - typeerror

Tags: json, parsing, typeerror

JSON.parse returns

> TypeError: Cannot find function parse in object

I've been using JSON.parse to receive info from a website. But suddenly it stopped working. The problem can be demonstrated really simple.

```
var s = "{\"virk\":\"test\"}";
Logger.log(s);
var b = JSON.parse(s);
```

> Error:
>   TypeError: Cannot find function parse in object [object Object]. Info ...

Comment: What is `Logger`?

Comment: @Soren_Rehne I copy this code and ran it, it worked fine. Can you be little more descriptive about input(string) and output(error)

Comment: You have old browser not supporting JSON operations or rewritten it's JSON object ? Seems JSON is not object with parse/strigify methods, but something else ?? Older browser would not know even JSON (guess).